# if else condition for placeholder text in jade template

Tags: pug

I am new to the jade template and trying to write a condition for input placeholder text.

My code

```
input#registrantEmailInput.form-control(type="email" name="registrantEmail" ng-model="regInfo.fields.email" placeholder={{ event._id!="12345"?"Enter Email":" " }} required)
```

Getting a syntax error - Unexpected token.

**Solution --**

```
placeholder='{{ event._id!="12345"?"Enter Email":" " }}'
```

Comment: It's sorted. Single quote was missing for placeholder. The post is updated with the correct syntax.

Comment: No, please don't do that.  This question will have minimal value to future readers as it was due to a small typographical error and this error already has answers in StackOverflow.  I have voted to close this question, but please also consider deleting it.